# Just installed spark and scala. Returns unsupported class file major version: 58

Tags: apache-spark

I just installed Scala and Spark. I ran the following code on spark shell

```
scala> val data = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(data)
scala> rdd1.collect()
```

It returns the following error messages

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)           at
org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)           at
scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
at
org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)                                                              at
org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)          at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2100)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1409)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1382)
... 49 elided
```

I have installed Java 8 and spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.6, and jdk-14.0.1. I have window 10. The error messages is totally incomprehensible. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be using java 8 to run spark. So change your variables so that JAVA_HOME points to version 8's installation directory (before calling spark-shell).

Comment: This is Java version error, use java --version and see which version you are running

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused due to the wrong java version being used with spark as some classes in different versions are either removed or changed.

If you want to set java environment for spark on yarn, you can set it before spark-submit/spark-shell by adding the below in the command:

```
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121 \
```

Or else specify the Java version in the spark environment configuration adding JAVA_HOME in conf/spark-env.sh https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Note that conf/spark-env.sh does not exist by default when Spark is installed. However, you can copy conf/spark-env.sh.template to create it. Make sure you make the copy executable.